# How to open link in a browser?

Tags: c#, .net

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("www.google.com");
```

It works perfect, but how about just 'google.com'?

I tried to do it like this

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("google.com");
```

but it doesn't work with the same links and throws an exception. Any suggestions?

Comment: where is the problem just to use "www.google.com"?

Comment: Did you try `"http://google.com"` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the protocol (`http://` or `https://` for example), then the handler knows what to do:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://google.com");
```

Windows checks the file extension list, and that included protocols too. There it finds `http` maps to your browser. You can consider to be 'lucky' it detects `www.` too, but I wouldn't depend on it too much.

Comment: No luck needed. The www prefix is detected by default.

Comment: What I meant was that "www.<any url>" works always with default settings.

Comment: @JensG whether it would be redirected to `www` completely depends on particular site configuration

Comment: @JensG: In this case yes, but it is safer to depend on the protocol then on the format of the url.

Comment: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\URL\Prefixes`

Comment: problem is there are many protocols and it's difficult to check my string. also my string can contains "www." and somthing else and i have to write regex ;( i hope there is easier solution.

Comment: @JensG: That is a nice one. Thanks.

Comment: @user3861153: Can you give examples of strings you should match and what they should no?

Comment: @user3861153: You should **not** rely on this behaviour, just add `http://`. I fully agree with that aspect of the question. Never said anything different.